# auto-generate geographical maps in java?

Tags: java, draw, geography

I'm trying to draw maps similar to these in Java:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to auto-generate them from a list of pairs (country,color) to determine the colors. Or (state,color) in the US case. I presume there must be common ways for this, as I find several websites generating them on the fly and sites like wikipedia have several which look exactly the same. But I fail to find information on how to actually generate them. How can I do this?

Comment: The basic idea is to use a predefined image, map specific regions of that image to a country. When you are finished mapping countries to colour you can simply fill each region with corresponding colour. I have always done the image-region-to-country-mapping by hand, but I guess that there can be tools that can do it automatically.

Comment: I have used [Google Charts for Maps](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map) for web-based app. Don't know if it will be helpful to you.